# Trackback not working in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, trackback

I have two controllers:
**test.php**

```
public function trackback()
{
    $this->load->library('trackback');
    $tb_data = array(
                 'ping_url'  => 'http://www.citest.com/addtrackback/receive/777',
                 'url'       => 'http://www.citest.com/test/trackback/',
                 'title'     => 'Заголовок',
                 'excerpt'   => 'Текст.',
                 'blog_name' => 'Название блога',
                 'charset'   => 'utf-8'
                 );

    if ( ! $this->trackback->send($tb_data))
    {
        echo $this->trackback->display_errors();
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'Trackback успешно отправлен!';
    }
}
```

function `trackback()` sends the `trackback` information

**addtrackback.php**

```
public function receive()
{
    $this->load->library('trackback');

    if ($this->uri->segment(3) == FALSE)
    {
        $this->trackback->send_error("Не указан ID записи ");
    }

    if ( ! $this->trackback->receive())
    {
        $this->trackback->send_error("Trackback содержит некорректные данные!");
    }

    $data = array(
                 'tb_id'      => '',
                 'entry_id'   => $this->uri->segment(3),
                 'url'        => $this->trackback->data('url'),
                 'title'      => $this->trackback->data('title'),
                 'excerpt'    => $this->trackback->data('excerpt'),
                 'blog_name'  => $this->trackback->data('blog_name'),
                 'tb_date'    => time(),
                 'ip_address' => $this->input->ip_address()
                 );

    $sql = $this->db->insert_string('trackbacks', $data);
    $this->db->query($sql);

    $this->trackback->send_success();
}
```

function `receive()` gets `trackback` and writes it into a table called 'trackbacks' in the database.

But when I try to view the page, it results in the following error:

> An unknown error was encountered.

What's causing this error?

Comment: Try using some var_dump on those trackback methods for us to understand better what is going on inside it, how is it receiving the information and returning it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

are you referencing the library or the function you're in? `if ( ! $this->trackback->send($tb_data))`

try changing it to something like

```
public function trackback(){
$this->load->library('trackbackLibrary');
```

what are you trying to accomplish because it seems like you're attempting to do an if statement for the same process.

```
if ($this->uri->segment(3) == FALSE)
{
    $this->trackback->send_error("Не указан ID записи ");
}

if ( ! $this->trackback->receive())
{
    $this->trackback->send_error("Trackback содержит некорректные данные!");
}
```

Also,
Check your error_log file to see what the actual error its throwing. `/var/log` or some other places. Depending on your OS